# Anywhere re-orders the sequence of the transactions

Tags: maximo-anywhere

We noticed that Anywhere is grouping and ordering the transactions such that the transactions for the parent [i.e.: Work Order] were sent first and then the transaction for the child records [e.g.: Specifications]

Scenario:
Step 1. Alter the description on the WO
Step 2. Enter Specification values
Step 3. Change the WO Status to COMP

The resulting transactions are sent as follows
Step1 and Step3 are grouped and sent to Maximo
On success
Step 2 is sent to Maximo

We want the messages to be sent in the same order that they happened and the reason for this is the validations we have in place in Maximo

e.g.: We validate if the child table has records [in our case, we check if the specifications are populated] before we Complete a WO

Due to the re-order of the events\transactions we are unable to COMP a WO from the device as the child transaction never gets to Maximo because the Parent transaction failing due to missing child data [catch 22]

We found the piece of code in the [/MaximoAnywhere/apps/WorkExecution/common/js/platform/model/PushingCoordinatorService.js] JS file that does this re-order and we commented out the reorder

```
//if (!transaction.json[PlatformConstants.TRANSACTION_LOCK_FORUPDATE])
//{
//    Logger.trace("[PUSHING] Trying to shrink/merge transactions and lock transactions");
//    var self = this;
//    var promise = this._shrinkSubTransactions(metadata, transaction);
//    
//    Logger.trace("[PUSHING] going to perform async operations");
//    promise.then(function() {
//        self._pushSubTransactions(transaction, deferred);
//    });
//}
//else
//{
    Logger.trace("[PUSHING] going to perform async operations");
    this._pushSubTransactions(transaction, deferred);
//}
```

Once this was done we were able to COMP the WO from the device as the events/transaction are now sent in the same order as they occurred

However, we have noticed that this has created another undesirable problem where on an error the device ends up with two Work Orders the one with the error and the one it refetched from Maximo

Scenario: We have an active timer running on the WO and we click on the clock. This will bring up the Stop Timer View and we select [Complete Work]

So there are two things that should happen the timer should be stopped and the status should be changed.
Due to some validation error from Maximo this transaction fails. The result is that we end up with the same wok order twice one with the new status and the error message and one it re-fetched from Maximo

Once we go into the record with the error and undo the change we end up with two identical WOs on the device

Apart from the above issue, there needs to be a way to clear the local data from the device without having to delete the app

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting some Model.save()'s in, or in the app.xml you can force a save when you show/hide a view.

Without the saves I think that everything gets put into one change ... sent as one message ... and you lose control over how it gets unpicked.

Answer (score 0):

Diggging this one up from the grave, but you can create something called a "priority transaction" that will capture all changes and package them in an isolated request and send it back to the server.

```
    westarAssignmentStatusChange:function(workOrder){
        workOrder.openPriorityChangeTransaction();
            workOrder.set(ATTRIBUTE,VALUE);
        workOrder.closePriorityChangeTransaction();
```

};

This will send an update to the server to change the ATTRIBUTE of the WORKORDER to VALUE.

We used this to isolate changes of specific items and made sure they processed in the appropriate order.